# .Net Core looking through Views instead of Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

My project is targeting .NET Core 2.1. I migrated from Framework and thus changed from Razor Views to Pages. The pages seem to be working normally when you access the whole URL (Controller/View), but when I tried to create a landing page for requesting the root address, my Page is not found. Seems as if MVC is looking through the wrong directory.

Error in question is:

> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched: /Views/Main/Index.cshtml /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml /Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml

My code for the route is just:

```
route.MapRoute("root", "", new
    { controller = "Main", action = "Index" });
```

Hoping to find some pointers for this.

Comment: I believe you are not allowed to have controller/action routing to handle the default (empty) route to a net core page. By default, the `index` page is rendered on the empty url and you can override that (https://exceptionnotfound.net/setting-a-custom-default-page-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/) By providing a route with controller/action mapping you effectively tell the runtime to find the controller/action for the empty url.

Comment: @WiktorZychla You're correct, I just found a similar source online. Had you answered, I would've marked it as correct. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: Isn't `Pages` akin to `WebPages` - where it's a _file_ based system instead of `controllers` and `views`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone who might find themselves Googling a similar thing, you'll be able to override Razor page options inside ConfigureServices() like this:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Home/Index", "");
});
```